# Java Collection concepts

Tags: java

I want to add unique objects in set but without overriding hashcode and equals method how to add unique objects to set 
without overriding hash code and equals method. IS it possible?

Comment: Define unique. If you need object identity, you are fine with the default implemenations of `equals` and `hashCode`. Otherwise, you need to implement at least `equals` (and for a reasonable Set implementation also `hashCode` or `compareTo`).

Comment: I have a class Employee and i have two same objects of the same class but i want to add to set.Ideally one should be added if i override Hashcode and Equals method. But is it possible without overriding the above method.?

Comment: *But is it possible without overriding the above method.?* No.

Comment: Without overriding equals method how are you checking whether the two objects are same or not?

Comment: Yes Ankit i am trying this without Without overriding equals method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HashSet doesn't allow you to do this however with a TreeSet you can provide a Comparator.

e.g. Say you have a class like `StringBuilder` you can't change but you want to add to a Set.

```
Set<StringBuilder> setsb = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Object::toString));
```

BTW: Don't modify an element of a set or key of a map after adding it to a collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. I got the solution and it is same as above mentioned by u

Comment: @RAJIVSARKAR Youc an accept an answer by ticking on the left hand side.